# Generalizing Ex6.14 from Atiyah-Macdonald: is $S^{-1}(M/N)\cong S^{-1}M/ S^{-1}N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In doing exercise 6.14 from Atiyah-McDonald

> Let $M$ be an $A$-module, and $a$ and ideal fo $A$. Suppose that $M_\mathfrak{m}=0$ for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}\supset a$. Then $M=\mathfrak{a}M$.

We need the following fact:

> $(M/\mathfrak{a}M)_\mathfrak{p}=M_\mathfrak{p}/(\mathfrak{a}M)_\mathfrak{p}$

This is not hard too hard to prove as $M/\mathfrak{a}M\cong M\otimes_A A/\mathfrak{a}$ and since localizing commutes with the tensor product we
$(M/\mathfrak{a}M)_\mathfrak{p}\cong M_\mathfrak{p}\otimes_{A_\mathfrak{p}} (A/\mathfrak{a})_\mathfrak{p}\cong M_\mathfrak{p}/(\mathfrak{a}M)_\mathfrak{p}$.

How much does this fact generalise? Is the following true?

> Let $M$ and $A$-module. Let $N$ be an $A$-submodule of $M$. Then $S^{-1}(M/N)\cong S^{-1}M/ S^{-1}N$.

Comment: Shouldn't this follow from the fact that localization is an exact functor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: the functor $M\mapsto S^{-1}M$ is exact so that the image of the short exact sequence $$0\to N\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow M/N\to 0$$ under it is a short exact sequence $$0\to S^{-1}N\longrightarrow S^{-1}M\longrightarrow S^{-1}(M/N)\to 0$$ This shows that $S^{-1}(M/N)\simeq S^{-1}M/S^{-1}N$.